# Send email before destroy User, Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm trying to hook a mailer before my User object is destroyed.

I am using Sidekiq to send emails but this error comes out when the User is destroyed.

`ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Couldn't find User with id [id]`

In my model I have this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :goodbye_user

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable

  private

  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
  end

  def goodbye_user
    GoodbyeUser.goodbye_user(self).deliver_later
  end

end
```

And farewell user mail never sends.

Any idea?

Comment: you could use a soft delete strategy when users cancels the account and hard delete after the email is sent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're sending the email asynchronously via `deliver_later`. Since it's on a separate thread, by the time the worker gets the job the user is already destroyed.

You can either send the email synchronously or don't use a `before_destroy` callback. If you'd like to send the email in the background, just call your `goodbye_user` method and destroy the user there (after the email is sent).

Comment: Good ideas.  Another idea: pass just the user data you need to the mailer - don't access the user itself since it no longer exists.

Comment: @MikePerham How can I pass this data to the mailer?, excuse me for my noob questions.

Comment: There is an example of passing specific data here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple Note as well that you should not pass a pure Ruby object as a parameter; use simple scalars that can be serialized to JSON and back.

Comment: As @anothermh said, you can pass the user object as a hash using something like `current_user.as_json`. If you need to append additional data, take a look at the [`as_json` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html).